# cookies header not present in swagger?

Tags: cookies, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-node-express, swagger-node

0 with express-session but i am not able to send the cookie i.e session.sid in header.its showing in curl but its not showing in server. So can anyone help me how to set it?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: This is the list of API pr
  version: 1.0.0
tags:
- name: developers
  description: Operations available to regular developers
host: localhost:3000
schemes: 
 - http
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: cookie
    in: header


/api/details/{id}:
  get:
    summary: List all
    description: ""
    produces:
      - application/json
    parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        type: integer
    security:
      - api_key: []  
    responses:
      200:
        description: " "
```

Comment: What `Cookie` value are you sending?

Comment: After authentication i m getting a cookie value that one only i have to send